# are there definitive guides for backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, backbone.js, sails.js

I've found a number of different resources and tutorials for backbone.js and many of them differ, which i suppose is by product of backbone being an un-opinionated framework, but honestly I find myself struggling to find clarity, I woud like to know what you've used to learn backbone, free or paid.

My goals are to use it with either a php backend (likely laravel) or with Node.js running Express and Sails.

Comment: I haven't found anything concrete but I have been referencing this: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Comment: I've seen that as well, slowly working through it, but should I take this as gospel and does it go far enough to have you building full apps ?

Comment: This is a great one - http://dailyjs.com/2012/11/29/backbone-tutorial-1/

Comment: will have a look, I'll start combining a these into a single answer after having a look, but ad them as answers so I can at least up vote your answers for your effort.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-backbone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There good screencasts:

- Tutsplus (Backbone and Larabel):

  - https://tutsplus.com/course/connected-to-the-backbone/
  - https://tutsplus.com/course/advanced-backbone-patterns-and-techniques/
- CodeShcool:

  - https://www.codeschool.com/courses/anatomy-of-backbonejs
  - https://www.codeschool.com/courses/anatomy-of-backbonejs-part-2

Also you can read list of tutorials in backbone's wiki:
https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites

Comment: Hey,  will check our the code school videos,  I do find video much quicker to get through as a resource,   I love Jeffery ways tutorials generally but had a incredible amount is difficulty getting through the laeavel pay on connrcted to back bone add alot of it seems out of date,  and left me a bit hanging regarding routing,  but still worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

as for myself, i consider [this](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/04/sample-application-with-backbone-js-and-twitter-bootstrap-updated-and-improved/) article which has help me a lot to understand the architecture of #backbonejs